# Where does heroku store uploaded files when using paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, paperclip

I have created a simple ROR application and installed paperclip with this configuration

```
has_attached_file :attachment,
  :path => ":rails_root/public/system/:attachment/:id/:filename",
  :url => "/system/:attachment/:id/:filename
```

then i created a simple form that takes the file as input from the user web browser, after that the file url is being displayed `model.attachment.url` and the user can download the file again.

I tried to run some linux commands to know where are downloaded files are stored `'ls /app/public/system/attachments/'` but couldn't all my uploaded files.

Also some files are being uploaded but when trying to get them back i receive 404 error!

has any one experienced such problem before?

Comment: heroku has read-only file system https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/read-only-filesystem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Heroku keeps paperclip uploaded images for few minutes then automatically removes them, it only keeps images residing in assets. To keep docs or images you need amazon s3 or other web services

Comment: I know that using S3 is the solution, i just wanted to know why they are being deleted automatically.