# Images not loading on rails heroku app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

For some reason when I tried to update my websites logo the image does not appear when I push it to Heroku, just the images' file name as a link. The images appear fine locally. I have png files saved in the images folder under my assets, so its not an issue of Heroku not finding it. I saw a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18324063/rails-4-images-not-loading-on-heroku) similar to this, but it really didn't answer my question. So why is the new image not appearing?

Comment: Hi David, I have answered this question already, here's the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20104005/where-does-heroku-store-uploaded-files-when-using-paperclip/20104359#20104359

Comment: I'm not using paper clip or doing any image hosting. I just want to change my logo image. I hope I don't have to get Amazon s3 just to host one image. That's a bit ridiculous...

Comment: You can't save images in Heroku dynamically, only the assets images are served

Answer (score 2):

This is my experience: [*ruby 2.30, rails 4.2.6*]

following heroku instruction [asset pipeline on rails 4](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-4-asset-pipeline)

in **config/application.rb** add setting below

```
config.serve_static_assets = true  # deprecated
```

use instead

```
config.serve_static_files = true   # Ok
```

in **Gemfile** add

```
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
```

then, as heroku says, [set ruby version in your Gemfile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions)

```
gem ruby '2.3.0'
```

Now you can update your dependencies running

```
bundle install
```

Then you should adapt your **source code**:

changing image_tag *"source_name"* everywhere it appears without extension

```
<link_to image_tag("icon") ... %>
```

with image_tag *"source_name"* with extensions (.png, .jpg or whatever)

```
<link_to image_tag("icon.png") ...%>
```

> You shouldn't run 
>   
>  *RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile* 
>   
>  because heroku does this for you during deploy.

...**and now is time to deploy**

```
git add <files modified>
git commit -m "comments your commit"
git push heroku <your branch>
```

This solved for me ... I hope also for you.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to show precompiled image. On heroku default mode is production.So it need to display precompiled images. When an image or assets are precompiled. It compresses the code and image gets renamed to for example:(image_42342j3n42b3n44234234.jpg) so you need to show this renamed image. Thus you need to add

```
config.assets.digest = true
```

this to your production.rb

Answer (score 0):

If you display images like

```
<img src='src_of_your_image'>
```

This will not work, because of [asset pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html), you have to use `image_path` helper

```
<%= image_path 'src_of_your_image' %>
```

[Image path](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html) helper will properly render you image even in production mode, after your images get their path distorted with custom hash.